# Etale $K$-theory of finite fields.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Do etale $K$-theory of finite fields coincide with algebraic $K$-theory? what is the easiest way to see this (I think etale and algebraic $K$-theory coincide above a certain value like cohomological dimension).

According to [this](https://www.gangeliniknoll.com/static/mastersthesis-6522004ab5152ebb7eee09aec289799f.pdf) theorem 4.4.3. The Bott inverted $K$-theory of finite field is given which should coincide with etale $K$-theory.
Now another question, why the Bott inverted $K$-theory given above is not 2-periodic? Isn't it supposed that all even degrees should match and similarly for the odd degrees?

Comment: I believe etale cohomology agrees with usual cohomology for "locally trivial sheaves/coherent sheaves". Maybe something similar is true for K-theory: Something like " the category of locally trivial/coherent sheaves on $X_{et}$ (in the etale topology) is equivalent to the category of coherent sheaves on $X_{Zar}$ (in the Zariski topology").

Comment: This is from Wikipedia: "For varieties defined over the complex numbers, étale K-theory is isomorphic to topological K-theory. Moreover, étale K-theory admitted a spectral sequence similar to the one conjectured by Quillen. Thomason proved around 1980 that after inverting the Bott element, algebraic K-theory with finite coefficients became isomorphic to étale K-theory."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory#Algebraic_topology_and_algebraic_geometry_in_algebraic_K-theory